# How do I repeat a string N times by replacing a character each time?

Tags: string, perl

I can repeat a string using this statement

```
print "(","arr[0],"x35,")";
```

which prints `(arr[0],arr[0],...,arr[0],)`

But how to obtain the output as below

```
(arr[0],arr[1],...,arr[34])
```

i.e; each time the string is printed, it should replace 0 with 0,1,2,..,34

Comment: In a loop, or are you looking to avoid using a loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print '(', join(',', map { "arr[$_]" } 0..34), ')', "\n";
```

Comment: Great!! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.